# Python add / merge rows of a dataframe together based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multiple-conditions

Good afternoon, I hope that you are well.

I have an xlsx file in the following format that which is output from a Python function I have been using to parse data :-

[image]

I have loaded this xlsx file into a pandas df in an attempt to achieve the following output :-

[image]

The requirements that I am trying to satisfy are :-
For each row in the dataframe, if the the "Application ID" and "Test Phase" column values match, then I would like to add the row values for those column values together and replace the original matched rows with one row containing the summed values.

Where there is match in the column values, the original row should remain in place.

If there any pointers on how to achieve this, it would be much appreciated.
I have attempted to achieve this code in the function prior to writing the values to the source xlsx output file however I assumed it would be easier to achieve by working with pandas / numpy.

Many thanks in advance
Jimmy

Comment: Hi experiment unit 1998X,
I hope that you are well.

Thank you for your reply.  Yes there could be scenarios where there are more than 2 qualifying rows of data, so the resulting single row should be the sum of the values in all of them.

Comment: please do not provide images of data, but rather data as text.

Comment: Apologies mozway.  I attempted to paste the values in directly from the sheet however it still tries to copy it in as image.  In future, I will provide a smaller dataset in text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby_sum`:

```
out = df.groupby(['Application ID', 'Test Phase'], as_index=False).sum()
print(out)

# Output
   Application ID Test Phase  Total Tests   A
0               9        SIT           36  36
1              11        UAT            5   5
```

Setup:

```
data = {'Application ID': [9, 9, 11],
        'Test Phase': ['SIT', 'SIT', 'UAT'],
        'Total Tests': [9, 27, 5],
        'A': [9, 27, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
   Application ID Test Phase  Total Tests   A
0               9        SIT            9   9
1               9        SIT           27  27
2              11        UAT            5   5
```

Comment: What happened to `as_index=False` instead of setting and re-setting? Do they also need `sort=False` and `dropna=False`?

Comment: If I use `as_index=False` I can't sum on numeric values.

Comment: But `df.groupby(["Application ID", "Test Phase"], as_index=False).sum()` gives the same output, doesn't it? I don't understand the reason...

Comment: I forgot the `numeric_only=True` by default! Nice point. Thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: For reference, your original answer worked for me (prior to your edit) :-

df.set_index(['Application ID', 'Test Phase']).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().reset_index()

If I try with the code you have edited it to :-
out = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum().reset_index()

I then get a "ValueError: multiple levels only valid with MultiIndex."

I am not sure if you have mistakenly edited out the column references from your original answer here.

Comment: No problem, thank you again for your help.